# Preventing modal window when the page is refreshing

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have a modal window (bootstrap 4) with on load function on my web page. Also I have a multipage gridview. When I open my web page modal window shows and there is no problem. But, when I click next page on gridview, page refreshes and modal window shows again. How to prevent showing modal window second time. Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).on('load',function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
     if(!sessionStorage.hasOwnProperty("isPopuped")){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        sessionStorage.setItem("isPopuped",true);
      }
    });
```

Comment: You should explain the solution :)